# C# IFormatable ToString("0.0000")

Tags: c#, tostring, iformatprovider

I have class and I want to reproduce the functionality associated with `ToString("0.0000")` as well as some other numerical formatting stuff.  How can this be done?

Comment: By implementing `IFormattable`, and writing a method that parses the format string and writes the output... was there a more specific issue?

Comment: I was hoping it could be done without regular expression stuff.  I was wondering if there was some internal class or something that "0.0000" was converted to or something.

Comment: There's a class called `System.Number` which has various formatting methods for the primitive types, but it's internal and the methods are all marked with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]`. Take a look using Reflector if you want to know more.

Comment: I didn't understood what you need to achieve; can you please explain it better, maybe with a sample?

Comment: You need to provide a more detailed question.  As far as I can tell, my answer below is an accurate answer, but I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  So I posted the answer as an approximation of what I thought the answer to your question would be, with the hopes of revising it once additional details were available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are probably your best bet.

Comment: Damnit.  That was my fear.  Thanks for confirming it I guess.

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to avoid RegEx?

Comment: This question is about formatting, not parsing.  Regex is inappropriate.

Comment: @nobugz: Ever heard of the `RegEx.Replace` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyNumber : IFormattable
{
   decimal value;
   public MyNumber(decimal value)
   { this.value = value; }

   string IFormattable.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   { return value.ToString(format, formatProvider); }

   public string ToString(string format)
   { return ((IFormattable)this).ToString(format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      MyNumber num = new MyNumber(3.1415926m);
      Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("0.0000"));
      Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0000}", num);
   }
}
```